# Reloading form after submit in flask

Tags: python, forms, flask, textinput

I am working with flask to display a wordcloud based on a file that is static in the system. After the page loads, I want the user to be able to input stop words to be able to update the word cloud on submit. With the current code the list of stop_words gets updated when the user submits a new stop word, but when the template renders again it does not update the word cloud. The get_nmf_topics(model, 20) creates a list of words and weights using a topic generator (nmf), and also deals with the stop_words in that function.

```
@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/word_cloud', methods=['GET'])
def word_cloud():
    try:
        words=get_nmf_topics(model, 20)
        # JQCloud requires words in format {'text': 'sample', 
                                              'weight':'100'}
        # so, lets convert out word_freq in the respective format
        words_json = [{'text': word, 'weight': weight} for word, weight in 
                      words]

        # now convert it into a string format and return it
        #return json.dumps(words_json)
        return json.dumps(words_json)
    except Exception as e:
        return '[]'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def parse_data():
    text = request.form['text']
    stop_words.append(text)
    print(stop_words)

    return redirect(url_for('parse_data'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using stop_words to add to the wordcloud therefore the word cloud will stay the same when you call the get method.

Comment: I also edited the post with this information, "The get_nmf_topics(model, 20) in word_cloud() creates a list of words and weights using a topic generator (nmf), and also deals with the stop_words in that function," so I believe that when the template is loaded for the home page, word_cloud should re-call get_nmf_topics().

Comment: Ok. Could you post the topic generator method as well? Everything in those methods seems legitimate